# Enforce unique values on calendar list by day

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, powerapp

I’m working a PowerApp linked to a SharePoint calendar that is used for office cube reservations.

I am trying to enforce unique values on my custom column for the list of cubes to prevent them from being double-booked, but by default this unique value is enforced across the entire calendar list.

Is it possible to enforce unique values by calendar day as opposed to the calendar’s entire list?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is not possible to enforce unique values in a calendar list by day. The OOB list setting work on a list range by default.

Second, if you are using custom list form using PowerApps, it does not check for duplicate entries before the form gets submitted.

A common workaround would be using Power Automate to check after the new event creation, and delete the duplicate entry if any. Here is an example: [Prevent double booking SharePoint calendar for the day.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Prevent-double-booking-SharePoint-calendar-for-the-day/td-p/267793)

In addition, there is a PowerApps Office Template named **Book a Room** that might do some help on this scenario.
Reference: [Office Template: Book a Room now available.](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/office-template-book-a-room-now-available/)